# wordpress $query->set by meta key value

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to modify all queries of a post type "products" to only show if the product/post has a certain meta_key of "wholesale_price" which the meta_value needs to be greater than 0.

Here is what i have:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'rc_modify_query_get_design_projects' );
function rc_modify_query_get_design_projects( $query ) {

    if($query->is_main_query() && $query->query_vars['post_type'] == 'product' ) {

    $query->set('meta_key', 'wholesale_price');
    $query->set('meta_compare', '>');
    $query->set('meta_value', '0');

}
```

}

For some reason this still returns everything. Is this the right way of doing things?

Comment: I think you are just missing `return $query;` at the end.

Comment: I have just added this, but everything is still returned.

Comment: Well, then try this instead : `$query->set( 'meta_query', array(
        array(
              'key' => 'wholesale_price',
              'value' => 0,
              'compare' => '>',
              'type' => 'numeric'
        )
  ));`  
instead of your :  
`$query->set('meta_key', 'wholesale_price');
    $query->set('meta_compare', '>');
    $query->set('meta_value', '0');`

Answer (score 4):

The problem is the method by which you are setting your `meta_query`.  You should read up on the [WP_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) functionality, because meta queries are unfortunately not that simple.

You need to do something more like so:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'rc_modify_query_get_design_projects' );

function rc_modify_query_get_design_projects( $query ) {
    // Do not add meta arguments in admin pages
    if (is_admin()) {
        return;
    }

    if($query->is_main_query() && $query->query_vars['post_type'] == 'product' ) {
        //Get original meta query
        $meta_query = (array)$query->get('meta_query');

        // Add your criteria
        $meta_query[] = array(
                'key'     => 'wholesale_price',
                'value'   => 0,
                'compare' => '>',
        );    

        // Set the meta query to the complete, altered query
        $query->set('meta_query',$meta_query);
}
```

And no need to return anything in this function.